# How to retrieve the response raster data of WPS using 52n-wps-client-lib?

Tags: wps, taudem, wpsclient, 52north

I'm using the `52n-wps-client-lib` to execute a WPS service, but when I try to retrieve the response raster data of the execution, I got an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.n52.wps.commons.WPSConfig.getActiveConfigurationModules(WPSConfig.java:223)
    at org.n52.wps.commons.WPSConfig.getActiveRegisteredParserModules(WPSConfig.java:237)
    at org.n52.wps.client.StaticDataHandlerRepository.getParserFactory(StaticDataHandlerRepository.java:60)
    at org.n52.wps.client.ExecuteResponseAnalyser.parseProcessOutput(ExecuteResponseAnalyser.java:195)
    at org.n52.wps.client.ExecuteResponseAnalyser.getComplexData(ExecuteResponseAnalyser.java:88)
    at org.egc.gis.wps.PitremoveTest.testExecProcess(PitremoveTest.java:70)
```

here is the WPS client-side code

```java
WPSClient wpsClient = new WPSClient(url);
File file = new File(testFile);
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
String dataStr = org.geotools.data.Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);

ProcessDescriptionType descriptionType = wpsClient.requestDescribeProcess(pitremoveFile);

ExecuteRequestBuilder executeBuilder = new ExecuteRequestBuilder(descriptionType);
executeBuilder.addLiteralData("only4", "false");
executeBuilder.addComplexData("dem", dataStr, null, "base64", "image/tiff");
//
executeBuilder.setResponseDocument("pit_removed_dem", null, "base64", "image/tiff");

ExecuteResponseAnalyser analyser = wpsClient.execute(executeBuilder, descriptionType);
// got NullPointerException
IData pit_removed_dem = analyser.getComplexData("pit_removed_dem", GTRasterDataBinding.class);
```

The response content of the execution is

```xml
<wps:ExecuteResponse service="WPS" serviceInstance="http://localhost:8080/wps/WebProcessingService?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&amp;SERVICE=WPS" version="1.0.0" xml:lang="en-US" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsExecute_response.xsd" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <wps:Process wps:processVersion="5.3.7">
    <ows:Identifier>org.example.PitRemoveFile</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:Title>org.example.PitRemoveFile</ows:Title>
  </wps:Process>
  <wps:Status creationTime="2022-04-12T22:35:30.093+08:00">
    <wps:ProcessSucceeded>Process successful</wps:ProcessSucceeded>
  </wps:Status>
  <wps:ProcessOutputs>
    <wps:Output>
      <ows:Identifier>pit_removed_dem</ows:Identifier>
      <ows:Title>pit_removed_dem</ows:Title>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData encoding="base64" mimeType="image/tiff">
          SUkqAAgAAAASAAABAw...(ignored to save space)
        </wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Output>
  </wps:ProcessOutputs>
</wps:ExecuteResponse>
```

I have reviewed the code provided by 52north [TutorialClientAPI](https://wiki.52north.org/Geoprocessing/TutorialClientAPI) to retrieve the result vector data:
`IData data = (IData) analyser.getComplexDataByIndex(0, GTVectorDataBinding.class);`

I'm confused why the similar code to retrieve the response raster data got an exception. I'm not sure it is because of the problem of server-side code or client-side code.

What is the right way to retrieve the response raster data of WPS using 52n-wps-client-lib?

The version of 52n-wps-client-lib is 4.0.0-beta.10

The corresponding server-side code was written based on 52°North WPS. The result data type is `GenericFileDataWithGT`

```java
private GenericFileDataWithGT result;

@Execute
public void run() throws IOException {
   this.result = new GenericFileDataWithGT(new File(pitFilledElevation), "image/tiff");
}

@ComplexDataOutput(identifier = "pit_removed_dem", binding = GenericFileDataWithGTBinding.class)
public GenericFileDataWithGT getResult() {
    return this.result;
}
```